# Jquery datatables pagination issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, pagination, jquery-pagination

So I have a map defined where there are two tables as an example. When you click on one item in the first table, it will highlight the corresponding related item/row on the second table. The issue I am facing is that I have added Pagination on these tables. So lets say when I select an item in table 1 and if it corresponds to an item in table 2 which is on page 2, when I click on page 2 on the second table, it loses the highlight.

Now I have the function which essentially has the objects which I care about but I feel I am missing the right jquery function (onclick/something else??) that I need to call.

ForEg: Lets say I pass the information during the below function. What happens is that the below function works when I click on the current page twice. i.e. Once to go to page and second when I am on that page.

Scenario:

- Click on item in table1 (that corresponds to item in table 2 on page 3)
- Click on button 3 to view the corresponding page (Ideally the below function should have been called but it doesn’t)
- Click on button 3 again and the below function gets called.

  `jquery(function1 + ‘ .page_button.current’).on(‘click’, function(e){
      console.log(“Entering here”)
  });`

I want it to be called when I go to that page for the first time.

Can anyone please help me with what I am doing wrong. What function do I need to use apart from this ‘click’ which would help?

Comment: Are you using the server side processing option in DataTables?  I believe you will need it for this to work.  That also means that you will need to handle which records are shown using server side logic.

Comment: Lets just say I am using server side processing and I have what I need to pass. I am just not sure which jQuery function to use to pass this info along through different pages.

Comment: jQuery doesn't care about pages. It works with elements in the DOM.  If a row is on another page, it is not in the DOM.  You can verify this by inspecting the HTML of your datatable. Therefore, using server side processing will allow you to control which records are fetched, which means you will apply your highlight based on which rows are currently showing.

Comment: In my scenario, jQuery thinks that all the records are fetched and doesnt know that its paginated. Thus it is having a hard time highlighting the next page, as it thinks all the records are on that page.

Comment: So when you inspect the HTML, all of the records show?

Comment: Yeah, thats the issue.